# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

While setting the development environment for Adhar(UIDAI) which is documented [here](https://www.developer.uidai.gov.in/site/node/24)

I am getting following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:
run (generate-sources) on project uidai-auth-proto-model: An Ant BuildException
```

As per the documentation after the navigating to the source code downloaded from here [here](https://www.developer.uidai.gov.in/site/downloads) we need to run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` in command line. After successful build we can import those projects into eclipse.

Success Build message
[image]

But I was unable to build due to some reason
[image]

My maven,ant and java config
[image]

**UID Protobuf Model files**

Git Repository of UID-Protobuf is [here](https://github.com/StackQuestions/UID-Protobuf-Model.git)

Comment: @Jens they haven't mentioned about ant in their documentation. Anyhow here is my `ANT_HOME` path in my system `C:\Users\Sai\AppData\Local\Ant\apache-ant-1.9.6`. My ant is working perfectly fine. I use is for building `Cordova`apps

Comment: can you show the pom file of `UID Protobuf Model` subproject?

Comment: Do you have `protoc` somewhere in the `PATH`?

Comment: @pingw33n no.. I dont have

Comment: You dont need ant maven-ant has nothing to do with ant

Answer (score 11):

The problem is maven-antrun-plugin is not getting build(executed). In uidai-auth-proto-model/pom.xml include plugins between pluginManagement tag as follows:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>generate-sources</id>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <tasks>
              <exec executable="protoc">
                <arg value="--java_out=src/main/java" />
                <arg value="--proto_path=src/main/proto/auth/" />
                <arg value="src/main/proto/auth/auth.proto" />
              </exec>
              <exec executable="protoc">
                <arg value="--java_out=src/main/java" />
                <arg value="--proto_path=src/main/proto/bfd/" />
                <arg value="src/main/proto/bfd/bfd.proto" />
              </exec>
            </tasks>
            <sourceRoot>src/main/java</sourceRoot>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <includes>
          <include>packaged/**/*</include>
          <include>in/**/*</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: THank You so much. I just added `<pluginManagement>` around `<plugnis>` tag and it worked falwlessly.

Comment: Definitely `<pluginManagement>` helps, thanks! I search for a solution a lot.

Comment: thank You much!  <pluginManagement>  worked like a charm for me!

Comment: pluningManagement tag was already present at my pom.xml, so i removed it and added to outer plugins of "maven-antrun-plugin" artifactId. and it worked. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have `protoc` (Protobuf compiler) in the `PATH` or in the project root dir. Make sure you use the same `protoc` version as the `protobuf-java` artifact declared in POM.

Comment: Please check the code of in UID Protobuf Model [git](https://github.com/StackQuestions/UID-Protobuf-Model.git) I believe, I already have in project

Answer (score 0):

Also, do same in uidai-auth-xsd-model/pom.xml as follow:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <goals>
            <goal>xjc</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>C:\Users\kumar.rahul@fin1.com\Downloads\uidai-auth-client-1.6-src\uidai-auth-xsd-model/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
            <extension>true</extension>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>C:\Users\kumar.rahul@fin1.com\Downloads\uidai-auth-client-1.6-src\uidai-auth-xsd-model/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
        <extension>true</extension>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```